# When do I have to specify the imported module (using `using`) to use a function, and when can I just use it?

Tags: module, julia

I'm new to Julia and there's a thing which I can't wrap my head around.

Say I have a file `my_module.jl` which have a struct and a function

```
struct MyStruct:
    foo
    bar
end


function fnc(x):
    println(x)
end
```

If I want to be able to use that in another file, `main.jl`, I have to make it a module and export the objects I want to be able to use in `main.jl` e.g

```
module my_module
export fnc, MyStruct

end

struct MyStruct:
    foo
    bar
end


function fnc(x):
    println(x)
end
```

As far as I have understood I can use the function and struc in `main.jl` without having to specify the module name, if I use `using` for importing i.e

```
include("./my_module.jl"); using my_module
fnc()
```

But if I use the `HTTP` package (important note; I'm using `using` and not `import` for the import) I can't just write `request` I have to write `HTTP.request` before being able to use the `request` function. I then looked into the `HTTP` module and I can see that `request` is not exported thus I thought that is the case, but it is not (if I move `fnc` outside the `module` scope in `my_module`).

So, can someone explain how I would alter `my_module.jl` such that I can use `MyStruct` directly but have to write `my_module.fnc` to use that, such that I can understand why it is like that in the `HTTP` package?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this explains it well:

https://syl1.gitbook.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/language-core/11-developing-julia-packages

First, let me specify that if all you want is to use objects (functions, structs, constants..) defined in another file, you don't need modules. Just `include` the file and its objects will be directly available to be used. Just be sure to `include` a Julia file only once.

It is however common to use modules, for sure if you want to develop a package (substantially a module + some metadata) but also if you want to keep code under separate namespaces or consider some code an implementation detail not to be directly used by some consumer's code.

Let's continue assuming you do want to use modules

It is true that "normally" you export the stuff of your package and don't those that you consider internal implementations, and that `using` brings into scope this stuff so you can call it directly, without referring to the package.
I don't know why `HTTP` developer chosen not to export almost everything, so that you need to explicitly refer to `HTTP.stuff` even with `using HTTP`. Perhaps they use submodules and they don't re-export, or they consider this API more "clean".. you have to ask them ;-)

Going back to your example, there are two issues. First you should declare the functions still within the module, before it ends, e.g.:

```
module MyModule # style note: typically starting with capital letter and using CamelCase
export fnc, MyStruct

struct MyStruct # no ":" needed
    foo
    bar
end


function fnc(x) # no ":" needed
    println(x)
end

end # end MyModulo
```

Second, if this is only a local module and not a package, that is with the metadata that lets Julia know how to retrieve it, you need first to include the file with `include("MyModule.jl")`.

At that point you can refer to its objects with a full reference to the module, e.g. `MyModule.fnc("abc")`. Alternatively, you can use `using .MyModule` (note the dot!) and then refer to the exported objects directly, e.g. `MyStruct(1,2)`

The dot is to indicate that the modulo is to be looked up relatively to the current modulo, that is `Main` (modulos are organised hierarchically). Indeed, you can use `using Main.MyModulo` as an alternative.